# git submodule によって管理されている Maven プロジェクトを EGit が認識しない

Tags: eclipse, maven, egit

`proja` と `projb` の Maven プロジェクトがあります(Javaのプロジェクトです)。これらは別々の git レポジトリとして管理されています。

これらは、別々に `mvn eclipse:eclipse` を実行し、Eclipse から Import すれば、EGit により、かってに git repository として判断され、 git 用の諸々の操作が可能になります。

次に、 `proja` と `projb` を、 `test-git` フォルダに入れて、submodule 化します。
つまり、次のような構成にします。

```
test-git/.git
test-git/proja/.git
test-git/projb/.git
```

このとき、最初の手順と同じように、`proja`と`projb`のそれぞれで `mvn eclipse:eclipse` を実行した後に Eclipse に Import しても、 EGit はこれらレポジトリを認識してくれません。

どうやったら、 Import した project を、 git レポジトリであるとして EGit に認識させることができるでしょうか。

NOTE: 問題の再現に submodule 化の必要ではありません。 `test-git` で `git init` して、適当にコミットするだけで、レポジトリを認識しない挙動は再現します。